# How to sort query string components by byte order in Scala?

Tags: scala, sorting, amazon-web-services

I need to create a string to sign for the AWS webservices.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html), it's required to sort the query string components by byte order.

For example, this:

```
Action=DescribeJobFlows
Version=2009-03-31
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
SignatureVersion=2
SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
Timestamp=2011-10-03T15%3A19%3A30
```

is sorted this:

```
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
Action=DescribeJobFlows
SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
SignatureVersion=2
Timestamp=2011-10-03T15%3A19%3A30
Version=2009-03-31
```

In my code I have the following method:

```
def getSigningStr(params: Seq[(String, String)]) =
        "GET\n" + host + "\n/\n" + params.map {
          case (k, v) =>
            val encV = URLEncoder.encode(v, "UTF-8")
            s"$k=$encV"
        }.mkString("&")
```

my `params` is a `Seq` which contains tuples. For example `("Action", "DescribeJobFlows")`. How can I extend `getSigningStr` to achieve a sorting by byte order?

Comment: Probably a bit misleading, I think they wanted to say that letter case matters. (Uppercase letters come before lowercase letters, they have smaller ASCII codes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost there , just use **sorted** for this ,this should work for you :

```
def getSigningStr(params: Seq[(String, String)]) =
        "GET\n" + host + "\n/\n" + params.sorted.map {
          case (k, v) =>
            val encV = URLEncoder.encode(v, "UTF-8")
            s"$k=$encV"
        }.mkString("&")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `.sorted` on the params before concatenating them into a string:

```
def getSigningStr(params: Seq[(String, String)]) =
  "GET\n" + host + "\n/\n" + params.map {
    case (k, v) =>
      val encV = URLEncoder.encode(v, "UTF-8")
      s"$k=$encV"
  }.sorted.mkString("&")
```

Alternatively - you can sort on "keys" only using `sortBy` before the mapping, but the result should be exactly the same assuming parameter names are unique:

```
def getSigningStr(params: Seq[(String, String)]) =
  "GET\n" + host + "\n/\n" + params.sortBy(_._1).map {
    case (k, v) =>
      val encV = URLEncoder.encode(v, "UTF-8")
      s"$k=$encV"
  }.mkString("&")
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to sort your header in lexicographic order. The amazon documentation required to sort by byte order - because byte order is case sensitive. See this line in the amazon documentation:

> Sort the query string components by byte order. Byte ordering is case sensitive. AWS sorts these components based on
>   the raw bytes.

So you would add `.toLowerCase` to your ordering condition, for example

`params.orderBy(_._1.toLowerCase)`

It is also a good practice to use a data structure with native ordering in Scala, for example, a `TreeMap`. Example:

```
var result = TreeMap[String, String]()(Ordering.by(_.toLowerCase))
for ((key, value) <- headers) result += key -> value
```

If your are looking for an AWS request signer in Scala you can check my fork at Github: https://github.com/allquantor/aws-request-signer

Ivan